# Prove that $\iint_A \operatorname{div} F\,dy\,dx=\int_a^bF\cdot N\,dt.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, line-integrals, greens-theorem

let $A$ be a region which is the interior of $C^1$ curve $C$ (oriented counterclockwise), such that
$$C(t)=(g_1(t), g_2(t)).$$

and $N$ is normal to the curve i.e. $$N(t)=(g_2'(t), -g_1'(t)).$$
you can check that easily by dotting $C$ with $N$ and getting $0$.

show that if $F=(P,Q)$ is a vector field on $A$, then $$\iint_A (\operatorname{div} F)\,dy\,dx=\int_a^bF\cdot 
N\,dt.$$

I don't really know how to prove this, I tried to use the fact that $$\operatorname{div} F=\nabla\cdot F=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}$$
but it didn't help at all, then I tried to evaluate $F\cdot N$ which also didn't help.

Comment: If you are allowed to use it, it is possible to show that this is equivalent to Green's Theorem (and you've already done most of the work if you want to show this). However, I personally do not know how to prove Green's Theorem.

Comment: How can i show that it’s equivalent to green’s theorem? @legionwhale

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4179886/568204) for Greens theorem implies divergence theorem.